# How do I migrate to Bitcoin XT from Bitcoin Core?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-xt

Some people are saying Bitcoin XT is faster and more secure, but I don't know how to migrate from Bitcoin Core to Bitcoin XT, because I have all my coins on Bitcoin Core.

What are the steps I need to perform to safely migrate from Bitcoin Core to Bitcoin XT?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking: Are you asking what is better, or how to migrate from one to the other? Please be more specific.

Comment: first thing i want to is better is stay remain with core or migrate xt? second wanted to know how to move my coins into new xt client,

Comment: We just do one topic per question post, so I'll leave it at the "how to move". "Which one is better" is primarily opinion based, so I don't think it would be a useful question, but if you are still interested in that, please create a new question for that topic.

Answer (score 4):

The two clients are based off of the same code base. To use Bitcoin-XT, you only need to make sure your Bitcoin Core client is shut off when you start the Bitcoin-XT client. The two programs use the same data directory and wallets, so all your coins will still be there.

See "[Should I be running Bitcoin Core or Bitcoin-XT?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38176/bitcoin-core-or-xt)" for more info regarding the differences between the two software packages.

In the README.md of Bitcoin-XT, it even says:

> XT uses the same data directories as Core so you can easily switch back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for an answer which actually addresses the question at hand, and avoids (both here and in the other referenced answer) any statements of obvious opinion....